# Android Print Bitmap - does nothing

Tags: android, api, printing

My code

```
PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(MainActivity.this);
                photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
```

When this code is executed nothing happens.
Should I see like a dialog for this or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should see a dialog in which you can select print settings and then perform a print. However, you'll need to first install a print service plugin from the Play Store, like HP Print Service Plugin. Make sure you enable the plugin after you install it - it is disabled by default. Additionally, your Android version needs to be Kit Kat or higher.